# Why won't XML Schema allow me to define a one-to-many key? And how do I do so?

Tags: xsd, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm falling over on a frustrating, arbitrary restriction in XML Schema. For some reason, it insists that PK-FK relationships have to be one-to-one. Why?

For example, given the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="FutureSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/FutureSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/FutureSchena.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/FutureSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="FUTUREFILE">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Configuration">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Experiments">

                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>

                    <xs:element name="Experiment">

                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="Profile" type="xs:integer"/>
                      </xs:complexType>

                      <xs:keyref name="dummy" refer="LP">
                        <xs:selector xpath="Experiment"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@Profile"/>
                      </xs:keyref>

                    </xs:element>

                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>

                <xs:key name="LP">
                  <xs:selector xpath="*/Configuration/Profiles/Profile"/>
                  <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
                </xs:key>

              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Profiles">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Profile">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And an example instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<b:FUTUREFILE xmlns:b="http://tempuri.org/FutureSchena.xsd">
  <Configuration>
    <Experiments>
      <Experiment ID="1" Profile="1"/>
      <Experiment ID="2" Profile="1"/>
    </Experiments>
    <Profiles>
      <Profile ID="1"/>
    </Profiles>
  </Configuration>
</b:FUTUREFILE>
```

Document validation throws an error if I define `<Experiment ID="1" FK="1"/><Experiment ID="2" FK="1"/>`, for example; i.e. more than one Experiment may not reference the same Profile. But why else would I want to use a key relationship? What use is a key relationship at all if I can't do something so fundamental?

OK, if  and  won't let me do this, how should I?

**edit #1:** As requested, I've padded out my code sample to include the full schema and a basic instance.

**edit #2:** Interesting. SharpDevelop's XML editor (as opposed to Visual Studio's) doesn't seem to object. It doesn't object to the foreign key value referring to a nonexistent primary key either (which IMO it should) but it's a start.

Comment: Please provide a complete short schema and instance, so I can do some experiments by myself. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Out of curiosity, what wasn't clear about how this was supposed to work, given my previous (incomplete) example? I felt it was enough to cover all the bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What wasn't clear ?... My english, it's all :-)

Some remarqs, I'm not sure it's solution :

In exemple instance, it's best to use `xmlns:b="http://tempuri.org/FutureSchema.xsd">`, and not `xmlns:b="http://tempuri.org/FutureSchena.xsd">` (n -> m).

Also it's best to put **b:** in front of all elements names.

According to your schema, you can't have two *Experiment* in *Experiments*, only one.

On xsd, put `<xs:keyref name="dummy" refer="mstns:LP">`, that works best for me ; it's because xpath expression doesnt't understand default namespace, see [Correct way to use key in xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545101/correct-way-to-use-key-in-xsd).

Comment: My apologies; my schema was a copied version of one I wrote at work, therefore I didn't get it exactly right. That version definitely did permit multiple Experiments with *different* profiles. Ditto with the spelling mistake in *schema*.

Comment: There we go. This led me to the correct answer - it seemed not to  be applying the key constraint correctly because of the default namespace problem. Furthermore, having rewritten the same logic **again**, the .net xml DOM now accepts one-to-many PK-FK correctly. What was wrong the first time, I genuinely cannot tell. Still, it works now. Many thanks.